# Show how many pages in Knp pagination

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

I install and override template in knp pagination. But I need show how many pages are. For example: 1 page of 10, 5 page of 10 e.t.c?I read offical documentation but I dosen't find ansver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override this template : https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Pagination/sliding.html.twig

Just use the variable `pageCount` to display the amount of pages where you want.

To do so, create a `sliding.html.twig` file in your `app/Resources/KnpPaginatorBundle/views/Pagination` folder.

Comment: [Check here for source](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/templates.md)

Answer (score 1):

I can see at the doc this abstract pagination class : https://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components/blob/master/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Pagination/AbstractPagination.php

This class has a method on line 113:

```
/**
 * Get total item number available
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getTotalItemCount()
{
    return $this->totalCount;
}
```